# How to read variables from the string using PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell

I have a TXT file which has the following text:

```
someCommandName -parameterName1 *abc* -parameterName2 *efg* -parameterName3 *hij* -parameterName4 *klm*
```

Would you be so kind to advise what how to code the reading of the `-parameterName2` and `-parameterName4` into the variable in the PowerShell script please?

Thank you very much for your help, in advance!

Comment: [`about_Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-5.1), [`about_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read your file into powershell variable then regex it?  Then iterate the matches or just use match 1 and 3?  (zero based array so parameter2 is [1], etc.).  Note I appended the " " at the end as it was needed to pattern match the last parameter with the grouping I did.

```
PS C:\> $file
someCommandName -parameterName1 abc -parameterName2 efg -parameterName3 hij -par
ameterName4 klm

PS C:\> $line = $file+" "

PS C:\> $regex = [Regex]::new("(.*?)-(.*?)\s+?(.+?)\s+?")

PS C:\> $matches = $regex.Matches($line)

PS C:\> $matches[0]


Groups   : {0, 1, 2, 3}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 36
Value    : someCommandName -parameterName1 abc 

PS C:\> $matches[0].Groups[3].ToString()
abc

PS C:\> $matches[1].Groups[3].ToString()
efg

PS C:\> $matches[2].Groups[3].ToString()
hij

PS C:\> $matches[3].Groups[3].ToString()
klm

PS C:\>
```